# How did the people know that John the Baptist was a prophet?

Tags: new-testament, prophets, john-the-baptist

What reasons gave the people to believe that John The Baptist actually was a prophet and wasn't a hoax? Was it simply the Holy Spirit calling on souls or was there some other kind of proof?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't overthink this one, LukeoX.

God obviously called John to be a prophet and a forerunner to His Son Jesus, the Christ (Luke 1:17). Consequently, in obedience to God's call John presented himself to the people as a witness, called by God to be a testimony to *the* Light. Put differently, John was a light to the people, and Jesus was the Light of the world (see John 1:4-9; cf. 8:12). John's little light paved the way for the big Light.

When people believed John's message, they proved the sincerity of their repentance by submitting to his baptism. They then became John's disciples (see Matthew 9:14; 11:2; Mark 2:18; Luke 5:33; 7:18; John 1:35; 3:25; and 4:1). The angel Gabriel told John's father that his yet-to-be-born son would come on the scene "in the spirit and power of Elijah" (Luke 1:17). In other words, John's preaching ministry would bear fruit, just as Elijah's did.

Now, what all was involved in being one of John's disciples is not exactly clear to me, nor does the Bible say too much about that. Unlike Jesus, however, I don't think John was called of God to form a denomination such as--oh, I don't know--Baptists perhaps!?
As the Christ's forerunner, he sort of faded into the background shortly after Jesus came on the scene. After all, John admitted humbly,

> "He must increase, but I must decrease" (John 3:30).

Not too terribly long after John made that statement, he was beheaded by King Herod. Interestingly, however, just before he died John told his disciples to ask Jesus,

> "'Are you the Expected One, or do we look for someone else?'" (Luke 7:19).

Despite John's greatness in Jesus' eyes ("among those born of women," Jesus said, "there is no one greater than John"), even he struggled with doubts about the identity of his cousin(?), the son of his mom's relative, Mary, whom John's mom called "the mother of my Lord"! (Luke 1:43).

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding me a little. I totally agree with everything you're saying about John and what the Bible declares. I'm looking to understand how people really knew he was a prophet. What I gather from your answer is the people simply believed, and maybe that was all there was. I was just wondering if there was a sign or something given to the people to validate is prophethood besides the one given to John's parents.

Comment: "God obviously called John" - it might be obvious in hindsight, but it was not obvious for the people back then, especially as Luke 1:17 has not been written yet.

Comment: @vsz: No, I stand by my statement. Luke may have written his Gospel decades after John the Baptizer's body was moldering in the grave, but the information he included in chapter 1 of his Gospel was widely available through word- of-mouth testimony for decades. Remember, Luke may have been a latecomer to the Christian faith, but once he became part of the Jerusalem contingent of believers, he was face to face with eyewitnesses of John the Baptizer's ministry. He was a good listener. Moreover, the Holy Spirit brought to Luke's mind the events God wanted included in Luke's Gospel. Don

Comment: @LukeoX: No, I don't believe a sign was given to the people to confirm John was called by God to be a prophet. True to the prophecy given to Zacharias, however, John would come onto the scene "in the spirit and power of Elijah." In other words, people would see in John a kindred spirit of Elijah. And don't forget the power of Elijah, who is best remembered, perhaps, for his confrontation with the prophets of Baal. Did John, like Elijah, perform miracles? The Scripture doesn't say. I tend to think he did not. His anointed preaching, alone, sufficed to bring conviction to the hearts of people.

Comment: To many people in John's audiences John may have been seen as a kook, a weirdo, a crazy man. To those who took the time to listen to him, however, John's quirkiness and strangeness probably faded into the background once the people realized he spoke with Spirit-anointed power and conviction. One final thought: Results, or fruit, are not the end-all and be-all of a ministry which originates in the call of God on one's life. Some of the OT prophets were probably discouraged by the general unbelief of their audiences. They kept on prophesying, however. Why? Because of God's claim on their lives.

Comment: All of that pretty clears up my question. Thanks @rhetoician!

Comment: @LukeoX: You're welcome, I'm sure. Or as the young people say nowadays, "No problem!" Don

Answer (score 1):

For all the Prophets and the Law prophesied until John (Matthew 11:13).

Commentary - “... ‘until John’ means up to and including John ... before the inauguration of the kingdom .... The Prophets and the law prophesied until then and, implicitly, prophesied of the new era ... the kingdom itself ....” (D. A. Carson, commentary on Matthew 11:13, The Expositor’s Bible Commentary (Vol. 8), Frank E. Gaebelein - General Editor, p. 268).

But if we say, 'From man,' we are afraid of the crowd, for they all hold that John was a prophet." (Matthew 21:26)
Commentary - “John was the last of a long history of OT prophets that looked forward to the coming of Christ.” (ESV Study Bible, p. 1842)

Comment: Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Answer (score 0):

1. John the Baptist wore 'prophet's garb', which was sackcloth. (This was one indication) (Other OT prophets wore sackcloth as well)
2. Jesus called John the greatest prophet in the Old Testament, so Jesus Himself called
   John one.

Jesus Testifies about John
Luke 7:
…27"This is the one about whom it is written, 'BEHOLD, I SEND MY MESSENGER AHEAD OF YOU, WHO WILL PREPARE YOUR WAY BEFORE YOU.' 28"I say to you, among those born of women there is no one greater than John; yet he who is least in the kingdom of God is greater than he."

3. Sackcloth was made with animal hair, and it was something that was often worn
   while fasting. Prophets, wanting to be close to the Lord, fasted.

Answer (score 0):

John the Baptist was an Essene ,separated group of Jewish Levite's. Kumron scroll confirms it .During that period Essenes lived away from cities their main job is to be pure to God ,their task to copy the Bible OT .people highly respected them hence they listened to John .

Comment: It would help your answer if you could provide source materials for your assertions (or assumptions).  For example, quote the "Kumran" scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The people knew John the Baptist was a prophet because it was prophesied that a messenger or prophet would precede the coming of Messiah.  Scripture records that an angel tells Zecharia John's father about this.

> And he shall go before him in the spirit and power of Elias, to turn the hearts of the fathers to the children, and the disobedient to the wisdom of the just; to make ready a people prepared for the Lord.
>   Luke 1:17

To be in the spirit and power of Elijah (Elias) was to be a prophet as was Elijah.

> And they asked him [Jesus], What then? Art thou Elias? And he saith, I am not. Art thou that prophet? And he answered, No.
>   John 1:21

Jesus wasn't the forerunner; John was, as Elijah.

In turn this fulfillment in John is of a prophecy that related back to this.

> Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of the great and dreadful day of the LORD: And he shall turn the heart of the fathers to the children, and the heart of the children to their fathers, lest I come and smite the earth with a curse.
>   Mal 4:5-6

To fully answer the question one would also need to understand the 70 weeks of Daniel and the timeframe of the expected Messiah.  In other words, they knew a prophet like Elijah would come first.  Suffice to say that some understood that Messiah would come by 5 BCE.  This meant that the forerunner (John in the power/spirit of Elijah) would also have to be on the scene.  This then is shown as mentioned above in Luke.

A prophet "foretells" or prophecies the future.  In John's case, his job as a prophet was to tell the people Messiah would and had come.  John was 6 months older than Jesus.

> The voice of him that crieth in the wilderness, Prepare ye the way of the LORD, make straight in the desert a highway for our God.
>   Isa 40:3

That's a powerful verse.

In addition, another function of a prophet was to annoint the king.  A priest would also do this.  And the trumpet would sound.

> And let Zadok the priest and Nathan the prophet anoint him there king over Israel: and blow ye with the trumpet, and say, God save king Solomon.
>   1 Ki 1:34

That was the foreshadow of Christ, son of David, being annointed at His baptism "by" John (prophet and priest) and with the voice of God heralding.

> And the Holy Ghost descended in a bodily shape like a dove upon him [Jesus], and a voice came from heaven, which said, Thou art my beloved Son; in thee I am well pleased.
>   Luk 3:22

So, the people knew John was a prophet.  It was prophesied.  It was required within a certain time.  It was fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

There are little of the expected cues and clues to clinch the question asked.
What sparseness there is has been given.
I can only add that there was an unusual yet genuine and ferocious loyalty demonstrated toward John which would confirm Jesus having accorded him- not greatest prophet status- but that of "greatest of men ever born of a woman".

Jesus was able to gain an advantage- knowing the fierce devotion of the Jews to John as the challenged leveled by the scribes, elders and priests to declare the source of His authority- He made them first answer about JOHN'S authority.
They did not answer because "they feared the Jews".  A wrong answer from them there would create more trouble than what they wanted for the answer from Jesus.

Can we glean from this that the Jews considered John the Baptist a prophet?
With that kind of loyalty- I would answer yes.

Answer (score -1):

Easy! Anyone that foretells of future events is considered a prophet. A true prophet is one that forecasts correctly. A Hebrew prophet from God is anyone that correctly forecasts about events that influence the Jews/Israelis or their nation. Therefore John the Baptist was considered a prophet.

Comment: Could you point to examples of correct forecasts from John? Otherwise I think your answer is incomplete.

Comment: You are using the wrong meaning/sense of the term.  The salient meaning/sense of the word "prophet" is *one who speaks the inconvenient truth.*  The OT prophets were all about that. Their role (for which few were thanked, and many were punished/abused) was to speak God's truth and to encourage / shame people into turning back toward God since they had already turned away from Him .... see also the the origin of the term *repent*